# Cannot use spring ApplicationContext in logback appender

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

Technology:
    spring boot,logback

I write a mail appender to reuse spring managed JavaMailSender.In order to get the JavaMailSender instance in spring ,I have this global static field in class

```
public class ApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {
    public static ApplicationContext applicationContextHolder = null;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        applicationContextHolder = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

In appender , I use the static field directly

```
if (javaMailSender == null) {
        javaMailSender = ApplicationContextHolder.applicationContextHolder.getBean(JavaMailSender.class);
    }
```

The problem is that field applicationContextHolder is null.I debug `setApplicationContext` method

[image]

and find applicationContext is injected.I thought the classloader may not the same one ,but `Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader` has the same toString value.
Anyone knows why?How can I get applicationContext in appender?

[start + in controller + in appender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B2kb.png)

Comment: Logging/Appenders start to work before the application is fully initialized. Your static field is probably still null when the appender code tries to use it. You could possibly work around that by storing all messages until you can find the necessary bean, then mail them.

Comment: Your ApplicationContextHolder is not annotated so it is nevercalled by Spring. Try to add `@Component` to the class

Comment: @StanislavL I declared it in another configuration class. In the first image, the setAppilicationContext method is called. In the second image, you can see that applicationContext is normal in a controller class.In the third image appender can't get it.

Comment: @zapl I did't use it at the start time. I wrote a test controller class and visited it in browser.So I think the application is fully initialized. In addition, I restarted my IDE in case of its problem.It did no help.